# What http IP address and port number should I put at the end of this FFmpeg command?

Tags: http, ffmpeg

The documentation on https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html explains the following command line as if set `listen` to `1` enables experimental HTTP server. This can be used to send data when used as an output option

```
ffmpeg -i somefile.ogg -c copy -listen 1 -f ogg http://server:port
```

What http IP address and port number should I replace `http://server:port` with at the end of this FFmpeg command above?

What kind of server is that waiting to receive the output from FFMPEG? Can someone provide code snippet in C++ or Java or PHP of such a server.

Comment: Server ip is the ip address of the PC where you run this command and you can choose any unused port as a server port. Here is a C example http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/http_multiclient_8c-example.html

Comment: And what can I do with this http url? Can I use it as src of the HTML video tag directly?

Comment: No, it broadcasts to that server/port. Typically a server in a datacenter, so your own ffmpeg machine can broadcast to that server, and the server can then broadcast it to anyone who's tuned in. Also called a relay server. Compare it to streaming to Twitch, you stream that somefile.ogg to twitch, so that many can listen to it.